# AWS + Nginx Auto Register

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

We would like to run our nginx instance inside our docker swarm running on EC2.

However, we would need them to be auto-registered with preferably R53 directly or possibly ELB.

Is that possible? Or do we need to run dedicated EC2 instances for NGinx?

Answer (score 0):

I know I should write out the complete solution, but it's too much to put in here.

If you use consul, consul-registrator and consul-template you can use one nginx per EC2 instance in front of all the docker containers. NGiNX' config will automagically be updated when a container stops or starts. You can then put an ELB in front of all your instances and just point it to port 80.

There's a great amount of documentation about this setup around, but some examples:
http://progrium.com/blog/2014/09/10/automatic-docker-service-announcement-with-registrator/
http://blog.xebia.com/2015/03/24/a-high-available-docker-container-platform-using-coreos-and-consul/